# Error computing in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 10,000 row x 21 column pandas dataframe called Rawdata. When I try to run an intensive loop with multiplications, Pandas returns incorrect values. In this code snippet, Volume Projections is my desired result. Does it have to do something with the intensity of the operation? How do I overcome this?

```
DesignOrders = 1856
ProjectedOrders = [1856, 2000, 2200, 2400, 2600, 2800, 3000, 3200, 3400, 3600, 3800, 4000, 4200, 4400, 4600, 4800, 5000]
ReferenceDOS = 19.41
ProjectedDOS = [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19.41, 21]

# Total Volume of the Pick faces in cubic meters - to be changed
TotalPFVolume = 900

# Have a dataframe for recording the volumes
VolumeProjections = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(ProjectedOrders), len(ProjectedDOS))), index=ProjectedOrders, columns=ProjectedDOS)

# Loop over Order-DOS combinations
for Orders in ProjectedOrders:

    for DOS in ProjectedDOS:

        # Hold atleast 1 CS for every SKU, project it for DOS and Number of Orders
        RawData["Quantity To Hold"] = np.maximum(RawData["Conv qty"], np.ceil((RawData["Sales past week"] / 7) * RawData["Long-term DOS"] * (DOS/ReferenceDOS) * (Orders/DesignOrders)))

        # Calculate Bartholdi ratio (for calculating volume) for every SKU
        RawData["Bang For Buck Volume"] = np.sqrt(RawData["Volumetric Sales"]  * (DOS/ReferenceDOS) * (Orders/DesignOrders) * 365)

        # Find total ratio
        TotalRatio = RawData["Bang For Buck Volume"].sum()

        # Replace ratio with actual BFB volume
        RawData["Bang For Buck Volume"] = RawData["Bang For Buck Volume"] / TotalRatio * TotalPFVolume

        # Find out 1.2 CS Volume
        RawData["MinimumCSVolume"] = np.maximum(RawData["IUM Volume"] * 1.2 * RawData["Conv qty"], RawData["PUM Volume"])

        # Find out minimum PF volume to be dedicated
        RawData["MinimumPFVolume"] = np.maximum(RawData["Bang For Buck Volume"], RawData["MinimumCSVolume"])

        VolumeProjections[DOS][Orders] = (RawData["Quantity To Hold"]).sum() #* np.maximum(RawData["IUM Volume"] * RawData["Conv qty"], RawData["PUM Volume"])).sum()

print(VolumeProjections)
```

my result: (incorrect values)

```
       10.00     12.00     14.00   16.00     18.00     19.41     21.00
1856   252547    287294    322825  421612    395644    422259    451707
2000   421612    304299    138075  382323    422057    450179    482359
2200   421612    326572    370035  365635    458287    489771    524832
2400   304299    350291    397797  445506    494441    528158    567891
2600   322902    373953    140991  479148    421612  17615067    610540
2800   342367    397797    141945  510671    567891    607883    652984
3000   362273    422057  14652740  543795    604576    646913    696055
3200   382323    445506    510671  575425    641021    686750    144132
3400  4519625    469833    539489  608290  30327399    727291    783465
3600   146528    494441    567891  641021    714196    766761    421612
3800   441878    518693    594357  673811    421612    147771    868649
4000   462241  18267073    624544  706889    789309    847669  57515529
4200   482359    567891    652984  739648    826273    887208    956270
4400   502443    591479    421612  772287    863490    928044    151766
4600   522892    616447   1104583  421612    899619    968482   1043823
4800   543795    641021    739648  837478    938120   1007977   1088304
5000   563243    665752    767614  872679    975470    421612   1130266
```

Comment: Is this indentation correct? The first `for` loop has nothing indented afterwards.

Comment: @johnchase I notice you attempted to edit the code based on the my indentation comment above. It's generally a bad idea to change someone's code since it can change the meaning of the question.

Comment: @chrisaycock thanks for the heads up. I had edited before I saw your comment, but will note that in the future. 
@Braggy in regards to the question, are you able to reproduce this error on a smaller data set? It may be difficult to answer this question without knowing what `RawData` is

Comment: @johnchase: Edited with the right code. I don't have any problem with small datasets. When I do it over 10,000 rows, it throws erratic results. I'm using Jupyter notebook (if that'll make any difference)

Comment: Python would raise a Memory error or something else not throw erratic results. If large datasets fail, so would small datasets. You post *incorrect values* but say you have no problem with small datasets. Plus, with each iteration of nested loop all values change. You do not save results.